# Remove characters from a string inside a for

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the folder location of a virus by removing the last 25 characters, i have found that this could be achieved with this  code that I have already tested and works fine

```
$string = "the scripts"
$string = $string.Substring(0,$string.Length-1)
$string
```

**Sample strings**

```
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\011_Leyendas\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\70'S, 80'S & 90'S.english\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\90\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\AlbertoBarro\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\BACHATA\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\CHICO CHE MEZCLADO\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe         
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\joan sebastian - M. A. Solís\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\JUAN GABRIEL 1 DUOS\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe
```

While trying to do it within a FOR the substring method doesn't cut the string correctly, some idea of why is not working any these sample code

```
$viruslocation = Get-Content -Path .\Desktop\virus.txt

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $viruslocation.Count; $i++) { 
    $Length =$viruslocation[$i]
    $tem= $Length.Substring(0,$Length.Length-22)
    write $tem
}

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $viruslocation.Count; $i++) { 
    $tem= $viruslocation[$i].Substring(0,$viruslocation[$i].Length-22)
    write $tem
}
```

**Expected result**

```
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\011_Leyendas\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
```

Comment: this what you want? $viruslocation -split ' (?=[a-z]:)'

Comment: or ($file -split ' (?=[a-z]:)') | split-Path if you just want the path

Comment: thanks the tip of the split-Path help to resolve the problem

Comment: for ($i = 1; $i -lt $viruslocation.Count; $i++)
{ 
    $tem= $viruslocation[$i] |Split-Path
   
}

Comment: `Split-Path -Path $_ -Parent` will return the parent directory given a file path.  If you're seeking all files with a given name go with `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | % Root | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter 'nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe' | % FullName | Split-Path -Parent` (loops through all subfolders of all drives on the machine on which it's run / returns the paths of any directories harbouring the given file name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GetDirectoryName` is what you are looking for:

```
$virusLocations = 'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\011_Leyendas\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\70''S, 80''S & 90''S.english\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\90\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\AlbertoBarro\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\BACHATA\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\CHICO CHE MEZCLADO\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\joan sebastian - M. A. Solís\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\JUAN GABRIEL 1 DUOS\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe'

$virusLocations | % {
    [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by @JohnLBevan, you can use the `Split-Path` command with the `-Parent` switch:

### MWE

```
$VirusLocations = @(
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\011_Leyendas\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\70''S, 80''S & 90''S.english\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\90\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\AlbertoBarro\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\BACHATA\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\CHICO CHE MEZCLADO\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\joan sebastian - M. A. Solís\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe',
  'C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\JUAN GABRIEL 1 DUOS\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr.exe'
)

foreach ($Virus in $VirusLocations) {
    Split-Path -Path $Virus -Parent
}
```

### Output

```
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\011_Leyendas\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\70'S, 80'S & 90'S.english\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\90\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\AlbertoBarro\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\BACHATA\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\CHICO CHE MEZCLADO\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\joan sebastian - M. A. SolA-s\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
C:\Users\jose\Desktop\MUSICA\JUAN GABRIEL 1 DUOS\nlwdvakybapcybqkvcfwr
```